# SQLite won't save data?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm using Python and I'm trying to use SQLite, however when I execute a command it never saves to the table.

```
# SQLite
# -
con = sqlite3.connect("comment_data")
c = con.cursor()
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS comments (id TEXT)")
def insert(id):
    c.execute("INSERT INTO comments VALUES ('%s')" % id)

def exists(id):
    c.execute("SELECT 1 FROM comments WHERE id = '%s'" % id)
    if c.fetchone() is None:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def commentCount():
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM comments")
    for row in c:
        print(row)

def close():
    c.close()
# -
#
```

When I execute `insert("random")` and run `commentCount()` it prints it. However when I close the Python application and run `commentCount()` it prints `None`. So how do I save data to the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must [`commit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.commit) the inserts.

```
con.commit()
```

> If you don’t call this method, anything you did since the last call to commit() is not visible from other database connections. If you wonder why you don’t see the data you’ve written to the database, please check you didn’t forget to call this method.

Comment: Haha thanks, such a simple solution... I've reviewed source code and haven't found this line yet..